# I have to remove the old row which is duplicate

Tags: vba

This is my table,

```
ID  Task    Status      Send by
1   Ring    Completed   raja
2   Sing    Completed   rani
3   Ping    Completed   Manthiri
4   Ding    Completed   Sithal
5   Wing    Completed   thief
6   Ring    Completed   raja
7   Sing    Completed   rani
8   Ping    Completed   Manthiri
9   Ding    OnGoing     Sithal
10  Wing    OnGoing     thief
```

By using duplicate function, I'm getting the result as

```
ID  Task    Status      Send by
1   Ring    Completed   raja
2   Sing    Completed   rani
3   Ping    Completed   Manthiri
4   Ding    Completed   Sithal
5   Wing    Completed   thief
```

But I need result as

```
ID  Task    Status      Send by
1   Ring    Completed   raja
2   Sing    Completed   rani
3   Ping    Completed   Manthiri
9   Ding    OnGoing     Sithal
10  Wing    OnGoing     thief
```

Kindly help.

Comment: Please reformat your data so it's readable.

Comment: Use Group by on task and then max on the ID field.

Comment: Post your code so that we can advise how to tweak it.

Comment: Is this Access of Excel? (Or something else?). You don't let us know the app you are working in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution will be to make use of Excel - VBA. Let me know if you face any issue in this macro or setting up the range dynamically.

```
Sub Maaya()

Dim Colm, lastrow As Integer
Dim Value1, Value2 As String

'Activate the sheet where you have the data
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

'Remove Duplicates and Sort the data
Range("A1:D11").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$D$11").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(2, 3, 4), _
        Header:=xlYes
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("D2:D8"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:D8")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
End With



'pick the last row of the data
Colm = WorksheetFunction.Match("ID", Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(1), 0)
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, Colm).End(xlUp).Row

'' Delete if there is a match
For i = 2 To lastrow

    Value1 = Range("D" & i).Value
    Value2 = Range("D" & i + 1).Value
' Value3 and Value 4 can also be used if your input changes and set it up to pick up the Task and then take it to the If loop accordingly

    If Value1 = Value2 Then
    Rows(i).Delete
    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help :) Small query I have here is... In range have mentioned as A1:D11 ... My work here is consolidate and then sort this Data... so How to give the range in this case as the number of data is not defined to me.

Comment: And I'm getting "unable to get match property of the worksheetfunction class" bug while running the code. :(

Comment: Made small change as Application.match instead of worksheetfunction it is working now...

Comment: @Maaya That's very easy. The idea is to set the range dynamically. See I have picked the lastrow in the code at some stage before the "FOR Loop". Use the same thing before declaring the range and Use Set range method. If you can't figure it out, ask a new question and I will have a look into it.

Comment: @Maaya no problem.